# Given a list of comparisons, sort items with as few additional comparisons as possible

Tags: algorithms, graphs, time-complexity, sorting, dag

You have `n` items `x[0], ..., x[n-1]`. Beforehand, you're given a list of several comparisons `c[0], ..., c[k]` for those items (e.g. `c[0] = (x[0] < x[4])`, `c[1] = (x[3] > x[7])`, etc.).

The objective is to sort the items by requesting **as few additional comparisons** as possible.

For example, if `c` contains all the pairwise comparisons, then you don't need to request any additional ones to be able to sort the list. If `c` contained nothing, then you'd request `O(n*log(n))` additional comparisons to perhaps quicksort the items. But if `c` contained something in between, how could we smartly leverage those existing comparisons to guide the extra comparisons we request?

Computation time doesn't matter (so long as it's sub-exponential). All that matters is the algorithm requests roughly the fewest additional comparisons.

Vaguely, I have an idea about constructing a DAG from the comparisons in `c`, and then doing a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) for the DAG to get a partial ordering, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Are you looking for a practical implementation or just a theoretical one like the current answer?

Comment: @SalvatoreAmbulando a practical implementation would be nice, but I was mostly interested in the theory

Comment: This paper talks about the problem and gives what they say is a more practical solution. I found it a bit easier to understand too. https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.0086 
I didn't know this was a question people were specifically studying before I saw your question, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is solved in Kahn and Kim, [Entropy and sorting](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S002200008571077X).